# How to prove that $\frac{x}{2}$ is smaller than $x$ for positive $x$

Tags: arithmetic

Could someone provide me a valid proof that $\frac{x}{2}$ is smaller than $x$. It seems obvious but i cannot think of a proof. Or just prove that $x+x$ is larger than $x$ for positive $x$.

Comment: $$\frac{x}{2} < \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x}{2}.$$

Comment: How do we know this is true?

Comment: You may want to look at the [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms)

Comment: You would have to prove that if $c > 0$ and $a < b$, then $a+c < b+c$.

Comment: So it is an axiom? That's great. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
x \phantom{\:+0} &= x \\
0 &< \phantom{x+\:} x \\
x + 0&< x + x \\
x/2 &< x/2 + x/2 \\
x/2 &< x
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Oh god, this was easy. Thanks a bunch :D

Comment: You're welcome. You could try just writing down Cameron's comment if this is homework or something and see what your teacher gives you. I doubt they'll require you to write down something as unnecessary as mine!

Comment: It's not homework, just something i thought of.

Comment: Alright. See if you can prove that $x/2 > x$ when $x < 0$, $x^2 < x$ when $|x| < 1$, $\sin x < x$ when $|x| < 1$, and even more!

Comment: These are easy, i don't know why i did not think of that. Brian fart i guess

Answer (score 1):

Note that if:

$$x>0$$

Then add $x$ to both sides:

$$x+x>0+x$$

Or

$$2x>x$$

Then we may divide by $2$

$$x>\frac{x}{2}$$